# Unity 4 PlayerPrefs not working on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have this code, it works on my Mac but it doesn't work on android. Any idea why?

```
    void StoreHighscore(int newHighscore)
{
    int oldHighscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt (name, 0);
    if (newHighscore > oldHighscore) {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt (name, newHighscore);
        PlayerPrefs.Save ();
        Debug.Log ("Highscore " + newHighscore);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is vague. What happens, and how does that differ from what you expect? Have you checked for any logs from your device? What have you tried to debug, so far?

Comment: Yes, when I try to retrieve the int, with PlayerPrefs.getInt, it stays at 0.

Comment: Your code seems fine. How do you decide the value for variable `name`? Are you sure it is the same each time ´StoreHighscore´ is called?

Comment: I call this method in another one, and it takes the variable from the other one for some reason. But, yes, I did a Debug.log and it's the same when it's about replacing. I'm just starting to implement serialization for this.